# How to choose kernel functions for support vector regression

Tags: regression, svm, model-selection, kernel-trick

Are there any good resources regarding how to design kernels for regression problems, specifically time-series regression type of problem. I am finding the choice of a kernel for regression extremely unintuitive.

For a classification problem with hinge loss, the idea is that the kernel should map similar examples closely while keep dis-similar examples apart. What is the equivalent notion for the ILF loss used in SVR?